# Is using the keyword "new" necessary here?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following pieces of code. Both work, but I do not understand if "new" has to be used or not.

```
Student oStudent;
oStudent = //Get student from database - Call business logic
```

vs

```
Student oStudent = new Student()
oStudent = //Get student from database - Call business logic
```

Both work - Should the keyword "new" be used only if it's a new student? If it's an existing student don't use "new". Student class is just a container class with properties like first name, last name, grade etc. My business logic class first gets student as a datatable and then assigns the results to the student container object and returns the student object.

Edit - 
My business logic does not do any complex calculation with the data. The data access just returns a single student as a data table and business logic change it into a student and returns it.

Comment: Those have different semantics depending on what your business logic code does and your `Student` Constructor does. Also, as a nitpick, please don't use Hungarian notation when creating variables. We know what type it is; calling it 'oStudent' doesn't serve any useful purpose.

Comment: Do you have some compelling reason to create a new student only to do nothing with it and throw it away?  For all we know you might have a reason for doing this (namely the constructor causing side effects), but you probably shouldn't be, no.

Comment: You don't, in fact, you shouldn't.  the new `Student` that you're instantiating with the `new` keyword will just get overwritten with whatever comes out of the db.  What I'd do is combine the two into `Student oStudent = //Get student from database - Call business logic`

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I would sure hope that the `Student` constructor doesn't do anything that would cause the end result of the 2 approaches to be different.

Comment: @SamIam You would hope so, but you couldn't know without seeing its definition.

Comment: That's the issue sam; without seeing the business logic and the constructor, we can't say.

Comment: Please consider adding something like `oStudent = GetFromDB();` to sample and show simplified, but reasonable version of `GetFromDB` method so it is clear what is happening. Most likely you don't need `new`, but need code to be sure.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker you can say that about just about any question that doesn't have all of the source code posted.  Going by the wording of this question("Is using the "new" keyword necessary"), Not only is it reasonable to assume that this is an academic question and that side effects in the constructor are out of scope, but it's unreasonable to assume otherwise

Comment: @GeorgeStocker There can really only be 1 reason to close that question, and that's if it somehow a duplicate.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker `Student class is just a container class with properties like first name, last name, grade`  The context implies that there is nothing crazy going on in the constructor of that class -- it is an entity class after all.  The OP's intent seems pretty clear ...

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I don't think this is opinion based. It's simple would I need it or no question. Sam and McGarnagle are right. My business logic does not do anything crazy. Data access just returns a single student as a data table and business logic converts the data table to a student.

Comment: So include that information in your question. As written we have to make assumptions about the state of your code; that wouldn't be helpful for future visitors because they can't see the state of your code if you don't share it.

Comment: @SamsonBujju That is not providing the requested information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern is foolish:

```
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
sc = SomeOtherValueOrFunction();
```

This creates an object and then discards it. Instead, just do

```
SomeClass sc = SomeOtherValueOrFunction();
```

Other example:

```
List<SomeClass> scl = new List<SomeClass>();
scl = GetSomeClassesFromDatabase();
```

Instead, just do

```
List<SomeClass> sc1 = GetSomeClassesFromDatabase();
```

The `new` keyword is for creating a new instance of a class. It makes no sense to create a new instance, then immediately replace it with a different instance.

Comment: To editors: I used the word "foolish" deliberately. I also deliberately did not use the word "stupid".